# Can I go to Switzerland while the Covid Certificate App is processing?

Tags: europe, covid-19, health

I'm traveling to Switzerland in a few days. My hotel says they check for covid vaccinations using the Swiss covid app. I have a vaccination from the US, but it takes up to five days for it to process into app.

Does this mean I have to cancel my hotel? Or is there some way I can get a valid EU or Swiss covid certificate sooner?

**Edit**: I'm going to Bern canton. I have a paper CDC vaccination card (with booster). I flying in to Zurich from Denmark, but am a US citizen. The hotel says it is under 2G rules.

I called the Swiss Covid hotline, and they said I might be able to get some sort of certificate in the airport? But they weren't completely sure, and didn't know if it would be open on Jan 1st.

Comment: What canton are you going to?  Where do you reside?  What is your nationality?  Do you have a paper CDC vaccination card?

Comment: There is no national rules on hotel guests although the establishment or the canton can adopt additional rules. If the establishment is under 3G rules, then a certificate from PCR or rapid testing suffices so you can book a rapid test in Switzerland (or an EEA country or other countries with mutual recognition of Covid certificates) before your arrival at the hotel.

Comment: However, certificates from a negative test are no longer valid for indoor dining, even if you are the guest of a hotel.

Comment: @phoog Thanks. I added more details. I'm going to Bern.

Comment: @xngtng I think this may be establishment rules, but could also be Bern rules... I wonder if there is an alternative / expedited way to get a valid certificate? Perhaps by going somewhere in person? I could also try to get an EU certificate from some other country, since those seem to be accepted in Switzerland?

Comment: I don't think Bern has implemented additional rules for hotels. You can ask the hotel directly if they are using 3G or 2G rules.

Comment: @xngtng They say 2G

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the edit; before the online platform it was possible in some cantons to go in person, but now most ask you to use the national platform (although I am not sure about Bern). Certificates issued by other EU states are also valid. You could also try asking for a refund and book another hotel without 2G rules.

Comment: I certainly would not count on this working out in your case, especially since many details are different, but in Geneva I have personal experience, on more than one occasion, of restaurant patrons being served after showing CDC cards and explaining that the application for the Swiss certificate is in process.

Comment: Ok, I guess we'll try the office in the airport and hope for the best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We ended up going to the Jdmt Medical Services in the Zurich Airport, and they gave us the certificate immediately.

Some other people hadn't even started the process online, but they also got a certificate, albeit after a bit more paperwork.

Surprised information about this option wasn't available online, but I guess they want to encourage people to use the online option.

Comment: Great news and thank you for reporting back! Could you perhaps add some more details on how/where to find the medical service office?

Comment: Right. It was in the middle of a mall connected to the airport. There is also some information at https://www.zh.ch/en/gesundheit/coronavirus/covid-zertifikat.html in the section "Request rejected or technical problems".

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer but a few data points:

Last time I tried (September 2021) to convert a US based vaccine certification (CDC card, smart health card, PDF doc) I failed. Nothing online I could find would accept any of my US credentials. They did accept my credentials at the airport on arrival for entry.

I was able to get an EU Covid pass in Germany, but since then Germany has stopped doing this, since the CDC card is just to easy to forge and you can buy them online in bulk.

Comment: Last I checked Switzerland was issuing certificates to tourists and other visitors based on foreign vaccinations.  I know that they issue certificates on the basis of CDC cards because they did so for me a week and a half ago.

Comment: The national conversion platform started in November. Some people have problems with CDC cards that are stickered instead of signature/stamp though (after all CDC cards are rather basic) and had to get a letter from the state health department somehow.

Comment: I don’t think issuing EU certificates to Americans will ever truly stop. Too much money involved in tourism from that direction. Czech Republic will likewise gladly issue you one.